# Memory leaks showing only for system libraries in Instruments

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, instruments

Memory leak snapshot with no "Hide system libraries selected"-
[image: Memory Instruments snap shot 1]

Memory leak snapshot with "Hide system libraries selected"-
[image: Memory Instruments snap shot 2 after hiding system libraries]

Do I need to worry for these leaks as after many memory cycles I have come up to this point wherein I do not find a memory leak source in my application.
Is my understanding OK ?

And this image shows memory leak in cycles and roots mode -
[image: Roots and cycles mode]

Comment: There're memory leaks in system libraries / frameworks sometimes, but we can say it's rare. So, if you don't find memory leak in your application and you're pretty sure, just write some simple example code and report it to the Apple via bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not sure where actual leak lies as there are more than thousand files in my project and as we know, I do not get exact location in my code if it is a system leak.

Comment: It looks to me like the image views are the root of that particular cycle. So, select an image view and see where it was created in the Extended Detail pane. You might also see if you can look up object history for a single leaked image view and see if you retained it at any point and forgot to release it.

Comment: @KaustubhKabra did u able to resolve your issue? I am having same issue. When am hiding system libraries my call tree and leaks shows nothing.